# Can Outlook display LDAP address book like MAPI personal contacts?

Tags: outlook, ldap, contacts

I was wondering how to handle LDAP address books in Outlook like MAPI one (display of all contacts in any way, like thumbnails etc...)

Of course, this can be a problem in cases of many entries, but i'd like to export all users a specific branch of my global LDAP AB. Class used in inetOrgPerson.

Actually, i can browse the contacts (only through the search field), else i have nothing under contact tab, whatever is the calendar i selected.

Is it possible ? Evolution is doing this very well, Thunderbird a bit less, but none are suitables for many reasons, so i'd have to stick to outlook 2007 or 2010.

My tests are based on outlook 2007 only.

Comment: My test LDAP is simple: cn, sn, mail, and nothing more. Perhaps i miss a point with equivalent fields avoiding contacts to be displayed as cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two things - IPM.Contact items in general have nothing to do with any address books. They are just items in one of Outlook folders, not any different from mails or appointments.

It is just that Outlook Address Book provider (OAB) happens to use those IPM.Contact items as its storage. Not all folders with such items are displayed as containers by the OAB provider.

Other address book providers (such as GAL) do not use Outlook items at all. LDAP is exactly the same way.

Comment: thank you. 3 years later, it is effectively more clear for me.